# 10 minutes timer in C#

Tags: c#, timer, console-application

I'm developing a C# Console Application and I need to add a timer that starts when I write "start" and automatically stops when have passed 10 minutes.
How can I do this using only the "static void Main()"?

I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Timers;

namespace myScript
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string getInput = Console.ReadLine();

            if (getInput == "start")
            {
                //start timer
            }

            if (//10 minutes have passed)
            {
                //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Define *main class* ... and show what you already tried/have. Your question is like: I need a program that does `x` and `y`, can you write it out for me ?

Comment: I need some more information to be able to help you. What should happen after typing start? Should the app block? should it be possible to start multiple timers?

Comment: @Jonas Thank you! I've just edited the question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
    using System;
    using System.Threading;

static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please type \"start\" and press ENTER");
                while (true)
                {
                    var userInput = Console.ReadLine();

                    if (userInput.Equals("start"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("Not correct, please try again");
                }


                var minutes = 10;
                Console.WriteLine("Going to sleep for " + minutes + " Minutes...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000 * minutes * 60);

                Console.WriteLine("Done...");

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
```

Comment: Do I have to add "using" something at the top?

Answer (score 2):

```
//start timer
//put this into your if statement
Timer timer = new Timer (1000 * 60 * 10);
timer.Elapsed += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //do something
    timer.Stop ();
    timer.Dispose ();
};
timer.Start ();
```

Try this, use system.timers not threading. This should start 10minute timer which does something and disposes itself at the end of operation.